# Code First Relationships

Tags: entity-framework

I'm having some unexpected results when using code first and I know it has to do with how EF is creating relationships but I can't figure it out. Here is what I have.

Product class, KitComponent class (hold a product, and a qty, etc)
A Product has many KitComponents
A KitComponent has many Products

End result is to show a product, and this product has some other products included as a kit.  It may contain 1 of a product or 2 pieces, thats why I need a KitComponent class / table, to hold the other info.

For the longest time I struggled with the ef relationships. The database would put the ParentProductId and Parent Product into the IncludedProductID and IncludedProduct. NOW i fixed that but don't know how but the IncludedProduct field is not being populated. The IncludedProductID is now correct in database. What Am I missing so that when I pull a product and cycle through the kitCOmponents that the IncludedProduct is not null.

AND on top of that, have I correctly described the relationships in the config?

Product:

```
public class Product
{

    public Product()
    {
        this.KitComponents = new HashSet<KitComponent>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<KitComponent> KitComponents { get; set; }
}
```

KitComponent:

```
public class KitComponent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UOM { get; set; }
    public int QTY { get; set; }

    public int ParentProductId { get; set; }
    public Product ParentProduct { get; set; }

    public int IncludedProductId { get; set; }
    public Product IncludedProduct { get; set; }

}
```

DBContext With fluent API code:

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<KitComponent> KitComponents { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(p => p.KitComponents)
            .WithRequired(k => k.ParentProduct)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentProductId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<KitComponent>().HasRequired(k => k.IncludedProduct)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.IncludedProductId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }

}
```

Simple Seed Method to Demo Data:

```
public class ProductContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ProductContext>
{
    private ProductContext db = new ProductContext();
    protected override void Seed(ProductContext context)
    {
        Product prod1 = new Product { PartNumber = "P1" };
        Product prod2 = new Product { PartNumber = "P2" };
        Product prod3 = new Product { PartNumber = "P3" };
        Product prod4 = new Product { PartNumber = "P4" };
        Product prod5 = new Product { PartNumber = "P5" };
        Product prod6 = new Product { PartNumber = "P6" };
        Product prod7 = new Product { PartNumber = "P7" };

        db.Products.Add(prod1);
        db.Products.Add(prod2);
        db.Products.Add(prod3);
        db.Products.Add(prod4);
        db.Products.Add(prod5);
        //db.Products.Add(prod6);
        //db.Products.Add(prod7);
        db.SaveChanges();
        var kitComp = new KitComponent() { IncludedProduct = prod2, QTY = 1, UOM = "EA" };
        prod1.KitComponents.Add(kitComp);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see you have described your relationships correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the property to load, you have to make the navigation property virtual:

`public virtual Product IncludedProduct { get; set; }`

All the code first conventions can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx

Comment: wow... i simply was focused on so many things at once. Thanks for seeing my gross oversight.